# How can I set the name of the threads created by DefaultMessageListenerContainer?

Tags: java, spring-jms

I am working in Java code, without using xml to configure spring.
I suspect I need to subclass it, but how can I do that and have spring use my version of it?
I tried this:

```
  @Bean
  public DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer() {
      @Override
      protected TaskExecutor createDefaultTaskExecutor() {
        String beanName = this.getBeanName();
        String threadNamePrefix = "MyThreadNamePrefix";
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(threadNamePrefix);
      }
    };
    messageListenerContainer.setConcurrency();
    return messageListenerContainer;
  }
```

At runtime I get this error if I do that:

```
Error creating bean with name 'messageListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [com/hexagon/apollo/tasks/TAplTaskConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'connectionFactory' is required
```

How can I make this work, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> Property 'connectionFactory' is required

The error is quite obvious, you are defining the container bean without setting the required `connectionFactory` property.

```java
/**
 * Set the ConnectionFactory to use for obtaining JMS {@link Connection Connections}.
 */
public void setConnectionFactory(@Nullable ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
```

It has nothing to do with the thread naming.

Furthermore, there is no need to subclass it; just inject a TE:

```java
/**
 * Set the Spring {@code TaskExecutor} to use for running the listener threads.
 * <p>Default is a {@link org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor},
 * starting up a number of new threads, according to the specified number
 * of concurrent consumers.
 * <p>Specify an alternative {@code TaskExecutor} for integration with an existing
 * thread pool. Note that this really only adds value if the threads are
 * managed in a specific fashion, for example within a Jakarta EE environment.
 * A plain thread pool does not add much value, as this listener container
 * will occupy a number of threads for its entire lifetime.
 * @see #setConcurrentConsumers
 * @see org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor
 */
public void setTaskExecutor(Executor taskExecutor) {
```